# Is there a definitive way to style a Matrix field in a Safecracker form?

Tags: safecracker, matrix

I'm using Matrix fieldtypes in a front end Safecracker form and to say it looks terrible would be an understatement... I'm wondering whether there is a definitive guide to styling matrix elements in safecracker / frontend forms?

Does anyone have any tips?

Cheers

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any front-end issues with showing interactive custom fields (aka Playa, Matrix, etc.) should be due to either:

1. Conflicting JavaScript
2. Conflicting CSS (classes/IDs)
3. Missing or corrupt files in the Themes/Third Party folder for the particular add-on

I've used all P&T add-ons as part of a Safecracker form (buffalo.com, getrightmusic.com, iacp.com, etc.) and as Lisa says it should look pretty much the same as the back-end counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

I generally just add {field:my_field_name} and the usual P&T goodness you get in the CP comes to the fore.

Comment: Thanks Steven. The thing is that sometimes you may want to change the styling to bring it inline with the site you're working on.

Comment: ah OK - I guess then you could wrap Matrix field with a div and id and then make edits to the core Matrix CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Jim,

Do you have a screenshot? The front-end matrix forms should look nice, similar to the back-end, in your Safecracker form.

Also, seeing the template code and version numbers would be helpful.

Thank you!

-Lisa
Pixel & Tonic

Comment: Just a general note about SE, it varies differently from other support systems in that you aren't supposed to answer a question with a question. Use the comments to ask questions and give a formal reply once you have enough information. This ensures all answers are of the highest quality.

Comment: Thanks Lisa. If I want to override the styling, do you of a best practice way of doing that?

Comment: Jim, have you seen https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/matrix_and_safecracker?  Is that the kind of customization you are after? -Lisa